# Linking data in 2 different Excel workbooks together

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to link data in one workbook to another.  So that when data is updated in one workbook, it automatically updates in the other one.  I tried using = then selecting the cell in the other workbook and enter.  That seemed to work so I did it for all the other rows.  Then when I reopened the workbook later on and it asked me to update, which I did.  It has now changed the formula and is not working.

As far as I can see, it has linked my data to a previous workbook.  I'm not sure if this makes sense.  Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-another-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2010_%E2%80%93_2013) will surely answer your question.